# Confidence Interval w/ true standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

[image]

I'm very scared that my calculations I did were wrong. Here is why: I assumed true standard deviation meant population S.D. However the question says the standard deviation is from a sample. So what exactly is true standard deviation?

I did a quick google search which gave me standard error. Isn't standard error the standard deviation of the sampling distribution? We are only given a single sample.

The second text highlighted is simply to verify if anyone else got  the answer 4.52-5.18.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the expression 'true standard deviation' is often used to mean 'population standard deviation', as distinguished from 'estimated standard deviation' or 'sample standard deviation'.

Then, in the formula $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n},$ you have
$\bar X = 4.85,\; \sigma = 0.75$ and $n = 20.$ This gives the CI
$(4.521, 5.179)$ in agreement with your result. (Because $\bar X$
and $\sigma$ are given to two places, some authors would suggest
retaining three places in the endpoints of the CI.)

Note: If the given SD were intended to be the sample standard deviation
$s = 0.75,$ then you would use  2.093 from a t table with $n-1=19$ degrees of freedom. But in that case the problem should have
said 'sample SD'. Also, note that parts (c) and (d) ask you
to find $n,$ in which case you would not know what DF to use,
and you would need to work at a deeper level than suggested by
the elementary drill nature of this problem